# Google Sheet button updates increases button textbox value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty good at VBA but transitioning to Google Sheet scripting is killing me:

I have a drawing shape, with a textbox named
(by the end product there will be 6 text boxes, with identical actions)

I want to have a script which makes it so when I click the text box, the value increases by one.

I also have a reset textbox, which says reset, and when clicked, will set all 6 other textbox values to zero.

In excel, I had the following: subs for each shape which increased the textframe + 1, and a reset sub, but none of that language works in Google.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used VBA. Google currently has no equivalent to textframe. It has been requested. There are a number of like things you can try. The link below has a few examples. The first sheet (menu) has a menu named testing. It has four options. On open they will show multiple options. There are three named Button1, Button2, and Button3. Each shows a count. The count is set to 0 on open. If Button1 is clicked, A1 will be 1 and the testing menu will change to Button1 count=1. Clicking Button2 will change A2 to one and the testing menu will now show Botton1 count=1, Button2 count=1, Button3 count=0. The menu option Clear counts sets all button counts back to 0. Actually, the menu is replaced each time. The buttons tab has buttons that increase cell counts in total or separately.The button text does not change. I hope this gives you some ideas.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ysr90k38hir-Kz8HTRY-vw6e7KFGJJWnNwlt2azzopk/edit?usp=sharing